# filter based on negative statement in R dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

i'm trying to filter based on a negative statement joined by `&` operator. the positive statement gives me the correct stuff i do not want, but somehow when i add in `!` to indicate the negative statement (e.g., `!(logic1 & logic2)`), it's not returning correctly.

here are the specifics, i want to exclude rows with ID that is in bad AND tagged as "no good" in the column `tag`.

```
bad <- c(101, 103, 107, 110)
```

the following positive statement returns the correct rows i do not want:

```
df %>%
 filter(ID %in% bad & tag == "no good")
```

so then i added `!` to indicate the negative:

```
df %>% filter (!(ID %in% bad & tag == "no good"))
```

somehow, this kicked out the folks with IDs matching `bad` regardless of whether `tag` had "no good". iow, folks with IDs matching `bad` were kicked out even when `tag` was blank (NA_character_).

what am i doing wrong here?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can modify to `|`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     filter (!(ID %in% bad | tag == "no good"))
#    ID  tag
#1 105 good
#2 109 good
```

#### data

```
bad <- c(101, 103, 107, 110)
df  <- data.frame(ID=c(101:110),tag = rep(c("good","no good"),5))
```

Answer (score 0):

@phoebe you can get the desired output using a slightly modified approach

```
df %>% filter (!(ID %in% bad) & tag != "no good")
```

> Generating test dataframe `df`

```
bad <- c(101, 103, 107, 110)
df  <- data.frame(ID=c(101:110),tag = rep(c("good","no good"),5))
> df
    ID     tag
1  101    good
2  102 no good
3  103    good
4  104 no good
5  105    good
6  106 no good
7  107    good
8  108 no good
9  109    good
10 110 no good
```

> Checking output

```
library(dplyr)
> df %>% filter (!(ID %in% bad) & tag != "no good")
   ID  tag
1 105 good
2 109 good
```